# nodejs fs seems greedy

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I've set up a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pagodajosh/6977727) to show memory usage over time of a small program that streams a file in from disk.

The memory allocated as `rss` in `process.memoryUsage()` never goes down. From other projects I know that another file read will be able to reuse some of that memory, but that memory is never released.

I know that when some other process(es) are contenting for memory, the OS can take underused memory and write it to swap, but that is only a temporary fix (and could lead my machine to run out of swap for no good reason).

Since this 'leak' is not in the javascript heap, I don't really think it has to do with the way I am streaming this file, but I would like some confirmation. Is there anything I am supposed to do to cause this memory to be released?

```
$ node -v
v0.10.20
```

Comment: is it the exact same file?

Comment: The gist is an arbitrary example where it streams just one file, but my actual projects upload and write/read many files.

Comment: @PagodaJosh It's most likely not that greedy; the file descriptor should have been closed (bind to `'close'` to know when). But, the Garbage Collector in V8 probably hasn't run yet to deallocate memory used by the stream. For me, streaming in a file around 330 MB, memory usage drops about 45-50 seconds after `'end'` and `'close'`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski my gist shows more than 450 seconds of node holding unto ~122 meg.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I would appreciate it if you could run my gist with your 330 MB file and post your results

Answer (score 0):

I got a problem that boils down to a minimal testcase very similar to yours - I did on-the-fly zip compression of files in a web server process.

For the sake of people who find this thread - according to bnoordhuis on [the node.js bugreport you opened](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6357), you have to **call your script with the options** `--max_old_space_size=32 --expose_gc` (adapt the 32 MB to whatever you want) and then **call periodically** `gc()`. This helped my test case, and hopefully my application too.

The default limit is 1.5 GB. Very surprising if you just want to stream some files, no more work to do on the server, no state to remember, and you used node.js "for efficiency" on a small server that has lots of other things to do.